# Jquery-related-selects

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm tryng to make 7 related select boxes with this script: https://github.com/tukutela/jquery-related-selects,

here the shot: http://vitrineonline.com/porra/

and so, the problem is: on the 3 select, the script stop to push up the script.
 could someone please just give me a hint of what is going on? thanks :)

the code:

```
<form id="example">
<ul>
<li><label>Produto</label>
    <select name="categoriaID">

    <option value="AC">Acessórios</option>
    <option value="CA">Calçados</option>
    <option value="RO">Roupas</option>
    </select></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li><label>Tipo</label> 
    <select name="tipoID">
    <option value="">Escolha &raquo;</option>

    </select></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
<li><label>Condição</label> 
    <select name="condicaoID">
    <option value="">Escolha  &raquo;</option>

    </select></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
<li><label>Tamanho</label>
    <select name="tamanhoID">
    <option value="">Escolha  &raquo;</option>

    </select></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li><label>Tamanho Disponível</label>   
    <select name="tamanho_dispoID">
    <option  value="">Escolha  &raquo;</option>

    </select></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li><label>Cor</label>  
    <select name="corID">
    <option value="">Escolha  &raquo;</option>

    </select></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li><label>Material</label> 
    <select name="materialID">
    <option value="">Escolha  &raquo;</option>

    </select></li>
    </ul>

</form>





$(function(){



    $("#example").relatedSelects({
        onChangeLoad: 'datasupplier.php',
        loadingMessage: 'Please wait',
        selects: ['categoriaID','tipoID','condicaoID','tamanhoID','tamanho_dispoID',    'corID','materialID']
    });



});
```

---

```
<?php 




$categoriaID = $_GET['categoriaID'];
$tipoID = $_GET['tipoID'];
$condicaoID = $_GET['condicaoID'];
$tamanhoID = $_GET['tamanhoID'];
$tamanho_dispoID = $_GET['tamanho_dispoID'];
$corID = $_GET['corID'];
$materialID = $_GET['materialID'];


$categoria = array();
$categoria['AC'] = "Acessórios";
$categoria['CA'] = "Calçados";
$categoria['RO'] = "Roupas";


$tipo = array();
$tipo['AC']['BOL'] = 'Bolsa';
$tipo['AC']['BRIN'] = 'Brinco';
$tipo['CA']['TEN'] = 'Tenis';
$tipo['RO']['CAM'] = 'Camisa';

$condicao = array();
$condicao['AC']['BOL']['NOV'] = "Novo";
$condicao['AC']['BOL']['USA'] = "Usado";
$condicao['CA']['TEN']['USA'] = "Usado";
$condicao['RO']['CAM']['NOV'] = "Novo";





$tamanho = array();
$tamanho['AC']['BOL']['NOV']['GRAN'] = 'Grande';
$tamanho['AC']['BOL']['USA']['PEQ'] = 'Pequeno';



$tamanho_dispo = array();
$tamanho_dispo['AC']['BOL']['NOV']['PEQ']['P']= "P";
$tamanho_dispo['AC']['BOL']['USA']['PEQ']['M']= 'M';


$cor = array();
$cor['AC']['BOL']['NOV']['PEQ']['M'] ['AZ']= 'Azul';
$cor['AC']['BOL']['USA']['PEQ']['M'] ['VE']= 'Vermelho';


$material = array();
$material['AC']['BOL']['NOV']['PEQ']['M'] ['VE'] ['ALG'] = "Algodão";
$material['AC']['BOL']['USA']['PEQ']['M'] ['VE'] ['FER']= "Ferro";






if($categoriaID && !$tipoID && !$condicaoID && !$tamanhoID && !$tamanho_dispoID && !$corID && !$materialID ){


    echo json_encode( $tipo[$categoriaID] );

    } 

    elseif( $categoriaID && $tipoID && !$condicaoID && !$tamanhoID && !$tamanho_dispoID && !$corID && !$materialID  ) {


    echo json_encode( $condicao[$tipoID][$categoriaID] );

} 





else {
    echo '{}';
}




?>
```

Comment: I think you need to fill out the rest of the datasupplier.php file, it only goes to the second level. else echos `'{}'`.

Comment: Louis, yeah, but i think problem is that the php script will returned the data on json mode, so i think that it have more to do with the json itself, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$condicao[$tipoID][$categoriaID]`

should be

`$condicao[$categoriaID][$tipoID]`

Comment: Never perfect! thank very much, Never one more question, why have to be in this way?

Comment: er...because that's how you setup your array